# Include Specific Attributes Active Directory Query for an ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
get-content .\GroupNames.txt |
ForEach-Object {
    $Group = $_
    $countUser = ""
    $countUser = ((get-Adgroup $group -properties members).members).count
    $Total_Count += $countUser
    If ($countUser -eq 0){
        $Total_Count++
        Add-Content $LogFile "$Group, No Members "
        }
    Get-ADGroupMember $Group -Recursive -include | Select @{label="Group"; expression={$Group}},sAMAccountName,Name, @{label="Date";expression={$Date}} | Export-CSV $LogFile -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
    Add-Content $LogFile "Total Count - $Total_Count "
```

Hi so my above code takes in a list of AD Groups in a text file ("GroupNames.txt").
It then grabs the member from each group.
What I am trying to have done is that as its querying Active Directory for the ADGroup member, I also want to be able to request other attributes besides the default sAMAcountname and Name. I would like for example like to get the user's department and/or title. Ideally, i'd store it in a seperate variable like $properties so that I am only changing this value when I run the script.

Currently, the output is $Logfile, an csv file, with columns department/title and any other extra attribute blank.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Store this `Get-ADGroupMember $Group -Recursive` in a variable and then loop through each member to get the properties you need to export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider that `Get-ADGroupMember` can also return computer objects or (nested) group objects.
Looking at your code, you only want in user objects in the output.

Also, If you want a CSV file with user details, you must **NOT** add simple message text lines into the same csv file, because thta will destroy the structure.
You need to create two separate files while doing this:

- a text (log) file where the messages go
- the structures Csv file where the user details are stored

Try:

```
# set the paths for both the log file (plain text) and for the resulting CSV file
$logFile = 'D:\Test\GroupReport.log'
$logCsv  = 'D:\Test\GroupReport.csv'
$inFile  = 'D:\Test\GroupNames.txt'

# write a starting line to the log file
('Log Started {0:g}'-f (Get-Date)) | Add-Content -Path $logFile

# gather the details of the group (users only) 
# filter out empty or whitespace-only lines from the text file 
$result = Get-Content -Path $inFile | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } | ForEach-Object {
    # first, try and get the group by the name from the $inFile
    $group = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -eq '$_'" -Properties members -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (!$group) {
        "Group '$_' does not exist" | Add-Content -Path $logFile
        continue  # skip this one and proceed with the next group
    }

    # retrieve the users that are member of the group (ignore members of type group and/or computer)
    $members   = $_ | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' }
    $userCount = @($members).Count
    $Total_Count += $userCount
    if ($userCount -eq 0) {
        $Total_Count++    # why this increment if there are no users???
        "$($group.Name) - No Users" | Add-Content -Path $logFile
        continue  # proceed with the next group
    }
    # now loop through the user members to get their details
    foreach ($user in $members) {
        # output the details of the user this gets collected in variable $result
        Get-ADUser -Identity $user.DistinguishedName -Properties DisplayName, Name, OfficePhone, EmailAddress, Description, Title, Department |
        Select-Object @{Name="Group"; Expression={$group.Name}},
                      SamAccountNameDisplayName, Name, EmailAddress, Description, Title, Department
                      @{Name="Phone"; Expression={$_.OfficePhone}}
    }
}

# write the total count and an end line to the logfile
"Total Count - $Total_Count" | Add-Content -Path $logFile
('Log Ended {0:g}{1}'-f (Get-Date), [environment]::NewLine) | Add-Content -Path $logFile

# now create the CSV file with user details
$result | Export-Csv -Path $logCsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi thank you for pushing me in the right direction. Do you have suggestions how to remove the empty rows in the exported csv file?